# is it possible to use postgresql copy command to load table data into java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, postgresql-9.4

i have a table in postgresql with about 40milion record. i want to fetch all table data into ram using jdbctemplate, when simply execute query 'select * from mytable' using jdbctemplate it take a long time to fetch data into application and map it to list of pojo class, when using copy command inside postgresql to backup table data into file, this process take just about 1 minute, my question is that is there any way to use postgresql copy command using jdbctemplate to fetch table data into java application an map it to pojo class ?

Comment: The JDBC driver loads the complete result into memory before your application can process it. You can turn that off by using a cursor [as described in the manual](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor)